# Python script that prints its source

Tags: python

Is it possible (not necessarly using python introspection) to print the source code of a script?

I want to execute a short python script that also print its source (so I can see which commands are executed).

The script is something like this:

```
command1()
#command2()
command3()

print some_variable_that_contain_src
```

The real application is that I want to run a script from IPython with the `run -i` magic and have as output the source (i.e. the commands executed). In this way I can check which commands are commented at every execution. Moreover, if executed in a Notebook I leave a trace of which commands have been used.

## Solution

Using **korylprince** solution I end up with this one-liner to be put at the beginning of the script:

```
with open(__file__) as f: print '\n'.join(f.read().split('\n')[1:])
```

This will print the script source except the first line (that would be only noise). It's also easy to modify the slicing in order to print a different "slice" of the script.

If you want to print the whole file instead, the one-liner simplifies to:

```
with open(__file__) as f: print f.read()
```

Comment: maybe look into the inspect package in python: http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/inspect.html. Specifically the `getsource` method

Comment: This type of programs are called Quine programs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing) I am trying to write one myself in python, its too damn difficult. :(

Comment: Why remove the first line? You get a script that, when run, prints out source code *that doesn't contain anything about printing its source code*. It's confusing. The first line isn't noise any more than the comments or asserts are noise.

Comment: @user2357112: it's a matter of abstract orthogonality vs practical convenience. I just want to have visual feedback of the commands used in some data analisys. I discards all the non-interesting part to have a cleaner output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As long as you're not doing anything crazy with packages, put this at the top of your script

```
with open(__file__) as f:
    print f.read()
```

Which will read in the current file and print it out.

For python 3 make sure to use instead
`print(f.read())`

Comment: Yes, this works only if put at the beginning of the script. If put at the end and I execute other scripts the last executed file will be printed.

Answer (score 5):

For the most simple answer:

```
import my_module

print open(my_module.__file__).read()
```

I also tried using the inspect package.

```
import inspect

import my_module

source_list = inspect.getsourcelines(my_module)
```

Will give you a list of strings with the source code defined in it

```
for line in source_list[0]:
    print line
```

Will print out the entire source code in a readable manner

Comment: This does not work for a script since I just execute it, not import it.