# How to get the current script's code in Python?

Tags: python, self-reference

I want to get the current script as a string in a variable in Python.

I found two sub-optimal ways, but I hope there is a better solution. I found:

1. The `inspect` import has a `getsource` method, but that only returns the code of one function (or class or whatever), but not the entire script. I can't find a way to pass the object of the entire script to `getsource`.
2. I could find the file location of the script file using `__file__` or `sys.argv[0]` and `open` it to read. But this seems too indirect to me.

So: is there a (better) way to access the entire script as a string?

If relevant: I'd prefer a Python 2.7 solution above a 3.x.

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve* with this?

Comment: Possible dup [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326002/python-script-that-prints-its-source).

Comment: Not quite the same it seems, and the answers provided don't really show how to access the script's own code, but rather, the code of other scripts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's for a codegolf puzzle.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question...

Comment: @jonrsharpe see [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68090/32381).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I had the same question. In my case, I have a data processing script that dumps the results to a file, and I'd like to record exactly /how/ it does it together with the results.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
import inspect
import sys

print inspect.getsource(sys.modules[__name__])
```

Or even:

```
import inspect
import sys

lines = inspect.getsourcelines(sys.modules[__name__])[0]

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    print "{:4d} {}".format(index + 1, line)
```

The file the code is contained inside is considered to be a Python "module", and `sys.modules[__name__]` returns a reference to this module.

**Edit**

Or even, as [@ilent2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372604/ilent2) suggested, like this, without the need of the `sys` module:

```
import inspect

print inspect.getsource(inspect.getmodule(inspect.currentframe()))
```

Comment: Or, with fewer imports but perhaps less readable: `inspect.getsource(inspect.getmodule(inspect.currentframe()))`

Comment: Remark: there's one case where it's buggy, it's the main file loaded in the zip file [linecache cannot get source for the __main__ module with a custom loader · Issue #86291 · python/cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/86291)